# Is there a way to access other apps data on iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, game-center

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to be able to read users scores on the games they're playing and to make something like "Compare Scores with Friends".
Is there a way to access other apps data (games scores to be exact) on iOS/Android? Maybe somehow thru the gamecenter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For android you can use a Content Provider to access data in another application, but the other application needs to make that content available.

You can't just read data that another application has. Obviously there are all sorts of security issues that will arise if that was possible